# Implement material design from Google I/O 2014 app

Tags: android, material-design, googleio

I really like the new Material design i the Google I/O 2014 app, I would like to implement some in my app. I been trying to looking at source code but cant figure it out how to implement, so my question is if someone knows is there are some easier examples? 
I have two design i mind, first one is to have a actionbar like this: 
It looks like i big acionbar with two spinner.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68771663/2014-09-09%2008.46.13.png

The second one is this one:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68771663/2014-09-09%2008.46.41.png

I guess that one is a bit tricky to answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is basically a regular `ActionBar` with a layout containing two custom spinners side by side, right below it. The bottom shadow of the `ActionBar` has been disabled by setting `windowContentOverlay` attribute  to null by adding the following line to the app theme (in res/values/styles):

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

You'll also notice a subtle shadow at the bottom of the layout containing spinners. That can be added by creating a shape drawable in xml with a gradient. This gradient is set to have a 270 degree angle with a dark start color and a light/transparent end color (can include a middle color as well). And now, you can add a `View` under the spinner container as follows:

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/<name_of_your_shape_drawable"/>
```

Now, coming to the second picture, we can clearly see that `ActionBar` overlay mode is enabled, which can be done by adding the following line to the app theme:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

If you only want a specific activity to have an overlay `ActionBar`, then you can add the following line before `setContentView`:

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

Moving on to the parallax effect of the top image, you'll first need to get the yScroll value in pixels of the scrollview/listview, and then simply translate that `ImageView` by half of the yScroll value:

```
    imageView.setTranslationY((float) (yScroll/2));
```

Refer to this link in order to get scroll values from a `ScrollView`: http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/

I'm not so sure about the last bit which involves an animation to color the `ActionBar` when the title layout touches it. Might have to look into the source code for that.

Comment: Thank you, that looks great! I did try to put a layout with spinner under the actionbar, but it didn't look good because off the bottom shadow. But now I know what to do! I'm gonna look into that link, looks like a good start. That animation for color the actionbar is really beautiful!

Comment: If you think my response resolved your query, please mark it as an answer.